# changing kafka retention period during runtime

Tags: apache-kafka, retention

With Kafka 0.8.1.1, how do I change the log retention time while it's running? The [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) says the property is `log.retention.hours`, but trying to change it using `kafka-topics.sh` returns this error

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --alter --topic as-access --config topic.log.retention.hours=24
Error while executing topic command requirement failed: Unknown configuration "topic.log.retention.hours".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Unknown configuration "topic.log.retention.hours".
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:145)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$$anonfun$validateNames$1.apply(LogConfig.scala:138)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$$anonfun$validateNames$1.apply(LogConfig.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:631)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JEnumerationWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions.scala:479)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$.validateNames(LogConfig.scala:137)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$.validate(LogConfig.scala:145)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.parseTopicConfigsToBeAdded(TopicCommand.scala:171)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$$anonfun$alterTopic$1.apply(TopicCommand.scala:95)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$$anonfun$alterTopic$1.apply(TopicCommand.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:43)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.alterTopic(TopicCommand.scala:93)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:52)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Comment: I got a stupid question...is a kafka message part of a log? In other words, setting the retention for a log means setting a retention for these messages. The kafka docs don't exactly make that clear to me.

Comment: kafka messages are stored in log segments, so I think the answer is yes

Comment: please create a new question instead of a comment @dtc

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`log.retention.hours` is a property of a broker which is used as a default value when a topic is created. When you change configurations of currently running topic using `kafka-topics.sh`, you should specify a topic-level property.

A topic-level property for log retention time is `retention.ms`.

From [Topic-level configuration](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#topic-config) in Kafka 0.8.1 documentation:

- **Property**: retention.ms
- **Default**: 7 days
- **Server Default Property**: log.retention.minutes
- **Description**: This configuration controls the maximum time we will retain a log before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the "delete" retention policy. This represents an SLA on how soon consumers must read their data.

So the correct command *depends on the version*. Up to [0.8.2](http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#topic-config) (although docs still show its use up to 0.10.1) use **`kafka-topics.sh --alter`** and after [0.10.2](http://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html#topic-config) (or perhaps from  [0.9.0](http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#topic-config) going forward) use **`kafka-configs.sh --alter`**

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --alter --topic as-access --config retention.ms=86400000
```

You can check whether the configuration is properly applied with the following command.

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --topic as-access
```

Then you will see something like below.

```
Topic:as-access  PartitionCount:3  ReplicationFactor:3  Configs:retention.ms=86400000
```

Comment: I did the above command, but it doesn't work! I can still can see the old logs. Any ideas please.

Comment: @Jack retention is a guarantee on minimum time span to retain data. If you see older logs that is retaining for at least the minimum. There are other configuration options for a cleanup interval and retention size that might help delete older logs.

Comment: Actually, this retention might never work. Because whenever it is trying to apply the retention policy the log files may be in use or the writer stream is kept open. That's why it always fails and the console/app log file reports this actually - check this out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194

Comment: Note that `kafka-topics.sh` is now deprecated. The new way to do that is: `$ bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name mytopic --add-config 'retention.ms=86400000'`

Comment: Does anyone know if the offsets for each topics are also controlled by this "retention.ms" property?

Comment: And once you are done with your testing, you can revert the retention time back to default value using:  `$ bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper <your_ZK_host>:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name <your_topic> --alter --delete-config retention.ms`

Comment: @user3366706 no, the offsets are controlled by a different set of configs.  At times, this can be confusing because if your offsets are only stored for 24 hours but your data is stored for 7 days, if you don't set new offsets for 25 hours (app is down or something) when you restart the app it will read from the beginning or end instead of the last offset.  It's usually suggested you keep the retention.ms and offset retention the same or close.

Comment: @ammills01 yeah looks like "offsets.retention.minutes" controls offset retention time, but as per documentation it is at the broker level, not topic level.

Comment: @RomainHardouin anyone know if i have 4 topic and i want to configure all four combine with retention.byte of 5 GB. How can i configure same?

Comment: what is the behavior when topic level (updated) retention value exceeds the server level default? (say broker level is 7 days but you set the topic level value to 15 days, which value would apply to that topic?)

Answer (score 72):

The following is the right way to alter topic config as of Kafka 0.10.2.0:

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper <zk_host> --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name test_topic --add-config retention.ms=86400000
```

Topic config alter operations have been deprecated for `bin/kafka-topics.sh`.

```
WARNING: Altering topic configuration from this script has been deprecated and may be removed in future releases.
     Going forward, please use kafka-configs.sh for this functionality`
```

Comment: if i have 4 topic and i want to configure all four combine with retention.byte of 5 GB. How can i configure same?

Comment: @ankit I don't think its possible to provide a single retention config for a group of topics.

Answer (score 8):

The correct config key is `retention.ms`

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk.prod.yoursite.com --alter --topic as-access --config retention.ms=86400000
Updated config for topic "my-topic".
```

Comment: if i have 4 topic and i want to configure all four combine with retention.byte of 5 GB. How can i configure same?

Answer (score 4):

I tested and used this command in `kafka confluent V4.0.0` and  `apache kafka V 1.0.0 and 1.0.1`

```
/opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-configs --zookeeper XX.XX.XX.XX:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name test --alter --add-config  retention.ms=55000
```

`test` is the topic name.

I think it works well in other versions too

Answer (score 2):

The answers with zookeeper option and kafka-topics.sh are deprecated. The current way to do this is:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server <server:port> --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name <my-topic> --add-config retention.ms=86400000
```

Comment: does it require a restart of the kafka service?

Comment: No, restart is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

--zookeeper is depricated for kafka-configs.sh, instead use:

```
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server <yourserver:9092> --alter --topic <your-topic> --add-config <config-name=value>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka 3.6

Go to kafka dir

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-a:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name data_dump.common_dump --alter  retention.ms=259200000
```