# Is a kafka message part of a log?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is a kafka message part of a log?

**Extra Context**

The reason for this question is because I don't think it's clear to a new user that a kafka message is a part of a log. In fact, the idea of a message being in a log sounds pretty confusing but I guess log means something else in kafka.

More importantly, I wanted to configure the retention of these messages [see kafka-retention-period question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129222/changing-kafka-retention-period-during-runtime#comment116403485_29129222) but you'll notice they call it `log.retention.hours`. Hopefully, that makes it clearer where this confusion comes from.

Comment: Have already answered this. Just posting it so others can see on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

Quote from another user: "kafka messages are stored in log segments, so I think the answer is yes"

Also, I've tested the `log.retention` settings and can confirm that it applies to messages. From what I can tell, messages are just a part of log.